# Sliding dot product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 1D arrays

```
x = np.random.rand(100)
alpha = np.array([2, 3, 4])
```

I will refer to the elements of `x` as `x_0`, `x_1`, etc.

How, in the fastest way possible, can I create a sort of 'sliding dot product' from this, more specifically the following 1D array:

```
array([2*x_0 + 3*x_1 + 4*x_2,
2*x_1 + 3*x_2 + 4*x_3,
2*x_2 + 3*x_3 + 4*x_4,
...,
2*x_98 + 3*x_99 + 4*x_100])
```

I can't think of a way that doesn't use for loops. I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

that's called [convolution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), in your case you want to use it in "valid" mode so that it doesn't pad with zeros.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100)
alpha = np.array([2, 3, 4])

res = np.convolve(x,alpha,mode="valid")
print(len(res))  # 98, you can count it yourself on a paper.
```